# What is the ideal xss value to set in maven options during a jenkins build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, stack-overflow

In `maven` jobs we have the maven option to set parameters. At present I am using a stack value `-Xss30M` in some jobs because we face this error with anything lower:

> [ERROR] error: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Most of our jobs handle values of `-Xss10M` or `-Xss15M`. I have tried to push this value further for testing purpose and see that it is capable of going up to `-Xss200M` .

- What is the significance of this stack value?
- Does a larger stack have a likelihood of crashing the build instance?
- Can a large `-Xss` value be pinpointed to memory leaks or other source code issues?

I am using a t2.small machine with 1CPU and 1 executor.

Comment: The stack size is used for parameters of methods (method calls etc.) and -Xss.. sets the stack size of the JVM...if you face SOE just enhancing the size is not the solution identify why this happens...Based what I found out and read (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) default stack size is 1 MB on Linux... so if you have to enhance that that would a part which I start to investigate why?